# How to change my class render based on Props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently creating a form. There is a textInput. I want to show a disabled dropdown select if the user write a incorrect postcode. If the user writes a correct postcode, the dropdown will be enabled and request data from a restful API.

The problem is: I am sending a props "disabled", but apparently it is not working.

```
class SelectJob extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jobList:[],
            selectedJob:'default',
            loading:false,
            disabled:true
        }
        this.getJobs = this.getJobs.bind(this);
        this.jobHandler = this.jobHandler.bind(this);

    }

.
.
.

componentDidMount(){
            this.getJobs();
            this.setState({disabled:this.props.disabled});
};


render(){
        return(
            <MDBRow>
                <MDBCol sm="2">
                    {this.state.loading && <FontAwesomeIcon className="align-middle" spin icon={faSpinner}/>}
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol>
                    <select
                        disabled={this.state.disabled == true ? true : false}
                        id="jobId"
                        className="browser-default custom-select"
                        onChange={this.jobHandler}
                        value={this.state.selectedJob}>

                        <option disabled value="default">Profissão</option>
                        {!this.state.loading && this.state.jobList.map(
                            (job) => <option value={job.code} key={job.code}>{job.desc}</option>)
                        }
                    </select>
                </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
        )
    }
```

No errors, but disabled does not work.
It remains enabled.

```
render(){
        let selectJobAlias;

        if (this.state.setted === true){
            selectJobAlias = <SelectJob disabled="false" addressPostCode={this.state.addressPostCode}/> 
        }
        else {
            selectJobAlias = <SelectJob disabled="true" addressPostCode={this.state.addressPostCode}/>
        }
```

Comment: this code hasn't issue. could you provide some code of setting `this.state.disabled` part?

Comment: @DragonWhite Edited. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but why wouldn't you just pass `!this.state.setted` to the `disabled` property?

Comment: (And `this.state.disabled` to the `disabled` property?)

Comment: (And why are you using state to store the property anyway?)

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a `return` in the `render` function? Or does it just know to render `selectJobAlias`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select
 disabled={this.state.disabled ? true : null}
                            id="jobId"
                            className="browser-default custom-select"
                            onChange={this.jobHandler}
                            value={this.state.selectedJob}>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you used the props directly than deriving a state for it.

```
<select
    disabled={this.props.disabled}
    id="jobId"
    className="browser-default custom-select"
    onChange={this.jobHandler}
    value={this.state.selectedJob}>

    <option disabled value="default">Profissão</option>
    {!this.state.loading && this.state.jobList.map(
        job => <option value={job.code} key={job.code}>{job.desc}</option>
    )}

</select>
```

and make sure you send boolean instead of string like this

```
<SelectJob disabled={false} addressPostCode={this.state.addressPostCode}/>
```

In case you do want to derive a state variable based on your props you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` [lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) method.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a need to maintain the state of `disabled` in your child component, which in this case is `SelectJob`. Rather, based on the code provided, it appears that whether the select is disabled can be handled using only props passed from your parent component (which is what I assume you are pointing to in the second render snippet).

```
    class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
           this.state = { selectDisabled: true };
        }


        handlePostalCodeOnChange = e => {
          const isValid = // by your logic determine whether postal code is valid
          this.setState({ selectDisabled: !isValid });
        }



        render(){
            return (
               // Pass any other necessary props
               <SelectJob selectDisabled={this.state.selectedDisabled} />
            )
        }
    }
```

Then, in your child component -- `SelectJob` -- simply look to the passed prop of `selectDisabled` to determine whether the select should be disabled (Note: I've adopted `selectDisabled` for a bit of clarity in our naming conventions).

Passing new props in this instance should trigger a re-render. Generally, as a rule of thumb, if you can achieve your functionality without the need for maintaining separate or additional state, and can rely on props, you should do so (see [Step 3](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) in 'Thinking in React').

```
    <select
        disabled={this.props.selectDisabled}
        // Remainder of your code here
    >
    ....
    </select>
```

Finally, without seeing additional code, your functionality would not qualify as one of the ['rare' instances](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) where `getDerivedStateFromProps` should be implemented.